# Azure Storage Account zoned redundant storage blocking

Tags: azure, storage, blocking

I'm using Azure Storage Accounts that are using zoned redundant storage. When I write a file and close it, Azure seems to block the file until it is replicated. Is there somehow a procedure to exclude folders? Or disable the blocking of a not replicated file.
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a procedure to exclude folders somehow, or disable the blocking of a non-replicated file?

According to this [MS-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/files-redundancy#zone-redundant-storage)

You cannot exclude folders or disable the blocking of a non-replicated file.

- Azure Storage Accounts that use **`Zone redundant storage (ZRS)`** replicate data synchronously across three Azure availability zones in the primary region. Each availability zone is a separate physical location with independent power, cooling, and networking.
- While using ZRS, there is no way to exclude folders or turn off the blocking of a file that hasn't been copied. When writing a file to a ZRS-enabled Azure Storage Account, the write process doesn't finish until all three availability zones' replicas have received the data. This ensures the data's durability and high availability. It also means that until the file is copied to all three zones, it is blocked. This is the intended behavior. You might want to consider using **`locally-redundant storage (LRS)`** if you need to write non-critical files and can tolerate minor data loss.
- Each file is stored three times within an Azure storage cluster to protect against data loss due to hardware failures, such as a malfunctioning disk drive.
- However, if a disaster such as a fire or flood occurs within the data center, all replicas of a storage account using LRS may be lost or impossible to recover.

**Reference:**

[Understanding Azure storage redundancy offerings - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-storage-blog/understanding-azure-storage-redundancy-offerings/ba-p/1431700)